# pass values from one screen to another?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to pass data's (String) from one screen to another screen. At the time of button click i need to pass values from first screen to the next screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass along data as extras in the intent that starts the second activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NextActivity.class); 
myIntent.putExtra("extra", id);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

In the oncreate method of your profile activity you can access the extras:

```
int id = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra");
```

If you are new to Android, it might help to read through the examples in the developer docs, like the [notepad tutorial.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Register an onClickListener for the button and pass the required data by adding it to the Intent.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class); 
                            intent.putExtra("extra", data);
                            startActivity(intent); 
             });
```

You can get the data in Activity2 by

```
String extra = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra");
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it (since you can access this value from anywhere) might be using sharedPrefrences. But that would depned on your application.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: the preferences are as the name said for preferences. Sharing data between screens is done best via the intent service that is supposed to do this.