# How to pass an int value from one activity to other

Tags: android

can anyone help what is the problem in my code

**Activiy 1:**

```
int view=1;
TabFunctionality.setFirstTabFunctionality(TabFunctionality.FIRST_TAB, 1);
Intent intent = new Intent(AdultTeeth.this, MainScreen.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("TEXT", view);                 
intent.putExtras(b);    
startActivityForResult(intent, TEETH_VIEW);
finish();
```

**Activity 2:**

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras(); int view=b.getInt("TEXT");
```

Comment: what error or exception u r getting ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass integer from one activity to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074097/how-to-pass-integer-from-one-activity-to-another)

Comment: Also look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047453/pass-values-from-one-screen-to-another

Answer (score 20):

You can directly use putExtra also.

**Activity 1**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AdultTeeth.this, MainScreen.class);
intent.putExtra("int_value", int_variable);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity 2**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int temp = intent.getIntExtra("int_value", 0); // here 0 is the default value
```

Comment: Hi i should get the value of view ,but amm getting defaultvalue as value of view in second activity when i print the value of view

Comment: In above u taken int_variable instead of that i took view as my integer value ;int view =1;

Comment: when i try to print temp its giving 0

Comment: TabFunctionality.setFirstTabFunctionality(TabFunctionality.FIRST_TAB, 1);
             Intent intent = new Intent(AdultTeeth.this, MainScreen.class);
          intent.putExtra("TEXT", view);
          startActivity(intent);
          finish();
             view=1 is global variable

Comment: activity 2: Intent i1 = getIntent(); 
   Show=i1.getIntExtra("TEXT",10);

        
      System.out.println("v-------------->"+Show);

Answer (score 4):

**Passactivity:**

```
 Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), Passactivity.class);        
 i.putExtra("font",selected_font);
 startActivity(i);
```

**Receving activity**

private int my_size;

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
     my_size = i.getIntExtra("size",20); // 20  for default value.
```

Comment: Hi i should get the value of view ,but amm getting defaultvalue as value of view in second activity when i print the value of view

Comment: declare in global in both activities

Answer (score 1):

The answers given are here aren't wrong but they are incomplete in my opinion. The best way to do this with validations is to make sure that the extra is taken from the previous Activity as well as the savedInstanceState which is the Bundle data received while starting the Activity and can be passed back to onCreate if the activity needs to be recreated (e.g., orientation change) so that you don't lose this prior information. If no data was supplied, savedInstanceState is null.

> Sending data -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name", "Daenerys Targaryen");
intent.putExtra("number", "69");
startActivity(intent);
```

> Receiving data -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);

    int no;
    String na;

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras != null){
            no = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("number"));
            na = extras.getString("name");
        }

    }else{
        no = (int) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("number");
        na = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("name");
    }

    // Other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**in first activity ::**

```
intent1.putExtra("key",int_score);
startActivity(intent1);
```

**second Activity ::**

```
  Intent i1 = getIntent();  
  int temp = i1.getIntExtra("key",1);                                                                                                               int temp = i1.getIntExtra("tranningscore2", 1);
```

Comment: See the question what he is asking and what u r replying ?

Comment: @Android Power please dont DV becase he really need to this code.it is difficult to solve problem so i have give new solution.

Comment: fter this line   Intent i1 = getIntent();  do i have to access by i1.getInt("TEXT"); right

Comment: it is key which you have use in previous activity

Comment: ya you can says like that here "TEXT" is your key

Comment: Hi i should get the value of view ,but amm getting defaultvalue as value of view in second activity when i print the value of view

Comment: getIntExtra should have arguments string and int,if i give only string it showing error

Comment: ya just copy and past same ::

Comment: i think your view value is 1 then it should return 1 but if you initialize with 2 it will give ans 2

Comment: Activity 1:TabFunctionality.setFirstTabFunctionality(TabFunctionality.FIRST_TAB, 1);
             Intent intent = new Intent(AdultTeeth.this, MainScreen.class);
          intent.putExtra("TEXT", view);
          startActivity(intent);
          finish();

Comment: activity 2: Intent i1 = getIntent(); 
   Show=i1.getIntExtra("TEXT",10);        
      System.out.println("v-------------->"+Show);

Comment: what is your integer value?means what si value of `view`

Comment: my integer value in activity 1 is view=1;

Comment: just checkout that is there any place `Show`variable  are initialize ?any make sure it is not static or final

Comment: second thing some time if we use tab activity this problem is raise with global declaration make it Private and particular scope of any class or method

Comment: can u give some other idea.may be becs of tabview even i think;

Answer (score 0):

use this code may its work.

```
intent.putExtra("Text", view);
```

activity 2:

```
int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("Text", 0);
```

where 0 is the default value.

Comment: Hi i should get the value of view ,but amm getting defaultvalue as value of view in second activity when i print the value of view

Comment: i dont know why its giving value of view 0 but i use this code many times it give the appropriate value which i put in activity 1.please make sure you dont put the value of view in Intent.putExtra("Text",view);check the value of view first in first activty

Comment: Intent i1 = getIntent(); 
   Show=i1.getIntExtra("TEXT",10);       
      System.out.println("v-------------->"+Show);

Answer (score 0):

**in first activity**

```
 Intent i = new Intent(name_class.this, name_class.class);
 i.putExtra("valu1",valu1);
 i.putExtra("value2", valu2);
```

**second Activity ::**

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String valu1 =bundle.getString("value1");
    String value2 = bundle.getString("value2");
```

Answer (score 0):

just pass it like a string and typecast it

Comment: Welcome to SO! While this may answer the question it is of low quality. You should consider adding an example and/or link that would be helpful to people with a similar problem.