# Passing values from one screen to another in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, listactivity

Heres my first class

```
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(First.this,second.class);
            startActivity(i);
            cat=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView_cat);
            String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("myString");
            cat.setText(s);
```

Heres my second class

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
        String selectedFromList = o.get("name");//(String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Intent i = new Intent(second.this, First.class);
            i.putExtra("myString", selectedFromList);
            startActivity(i);
    }
```

I want to go to the second class (second screen) after clicking button of first(on first screen). Then i want to access the value of listitem selected in second class(screen) in first(screen). But having problem in doing that. Help would be appreciated..!!

I am enabled to pass the value from first.class to second.class but i want to take value in second.class and access it in first.class.. !! Theres the problem...!!!

Thanx.

Comment: Could you give the error raised? As far as I know, you seems to do the right thing : get the clicked item, get the data you're interseted in, putExtra, and start the activity.
Maybe there is a problem in your class naming.
What the logcat is saying?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to access the value?

Comment: Consider using [Activity.startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) in your case.

Comment: It was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3047503/771300

Comment: I want to access the value from second class in first one..

Comment: use startActivityForResult() it will work for u...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to pass variables.

1) Use the extra value of your intent:

```
myIntent.putExtra(String name, Bundle value);
```

Here is the android documentaton on that.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)

2)  Use an application class.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html
The application class creates a singleon that you can use to make data avaible to any activity. The activity references the application through

```
activity.getApplication();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication()